# How to unmount read-only file system and resize it. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, read-only, unmount

I need to resize `/dev/nvme0n1p1` partition because it takes almost all memory from my SSD. And also I couldn't make dual boot for Windows as second OS, so I need help.

I've tried this commands to change read-only files to read-write, but just don't understand why it didn't make any changes.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /

sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

also this commands

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/nvme0n1p1 
sudo mount -vo remount,rw /
```

I couldn't provide screenshots from Gparted app yet, because I just create my account, it displays this massege while I tried unmount the partition manualy...

```
Could not unmount /dev/nvme0n1p1 
#unmount -v '/'
unmount:/:target is busy
```

Thanks for any help guys

Here the output of this command `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.66 MiB, 58363904 bytes, 113992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 74.11 MiB, 77713408 bytes, 151784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 155.63 MiB, 163188736 bytes, 318728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 262.09 MiB, 274821120 bytes, 536760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 349.7 MiB, 366682112 bytes, 716176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 248.76 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: Timetec MS10                            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 847731F5-0940-469A-9630-B5819D5EFCF6

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 2000408575 1999357952 953.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 496.98 MiB, 521121792 bytes, 1017816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 81.26 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 45.86 MiB, 48087040 bytes, 93920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 12.32 MiB, 12922880 bytes, 25240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 40.43 MiB, 42393600 bytes, 82800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 452 KiB, 462848 bytes, 904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 659.28 MiB, 691302400 bytes, 1350200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Does [How to resize partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) help?

Comment: This solutions is for other issues. actually I need to make read-only file system read-write, because it is not possible to resize read-only files

Comment: @rusty  the output of this command posted

Comment: Your SSD has two partitions, one with EFI, and other with Linux system / (root) partition. You are trying to unmount your system partition from the system you are booted into, you should instead be using a Live Environment like booting from a USB stick. Then the process is well described in the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/212123

Comment: You need to download a .ISO image of Ubuntu desktop, backup your data (just in case), flash it to a USB stick, boot up, launch Gparted app and resize.

Comment: I did it before ask about it here but got this message Could not unmount /dev/nvme0n1p1 
#unmount -v '/'
unmount:/:target is busy

Comment: That shouldn't have been mounted in the live environment! Are you sure you've booted using live USB and not mounted that SSD partition manually?

Comment: Yes it is Live Bootable USB called Ventoy

Comment: Yes ventoy can be used to prepare your USB stick to make it bootable, then you copy the .ISO file to the USB stick's partition and boot with the stick.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'll try it